# A conjecture of Blakley and Dixon about odd powers of positive matrices

Tags: reference-request, conjectures, nonnegative-matrices, matrix-equations

In a [1966 paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X66900564) Blakley and Dixon conjecture the following. Let $S$ be a symmetric matrix with nonnegative entries and let $u$ be a unit vector with nonnegative entries. For integers $k\ge j$ **both odd**,

$$\langle u, S^ku\rangle^j\ge \langle u, S^ju\rangle^k.$$

They verify this conjecture under the condition that RHS is sufficiently large. I am wondering if there has been any progress towards this conjecture.

A year earlier, [Blakley and Roy](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-06/S0002-9939-1965-0184950-9/S0002-9939-1965-0184950-9.pdf) verify the $j=1$ case. This also implies that the conjecture is true whenever $j$ divides $k$. 
There are no papers known to Google scholar citing this paper that solves the conjecture.

Comment: If $S$ is in addition positive definite, then clearly the conjecture is true. Otherwise, you could try to generalize the proof of T. Pate, and see if holds: http://www.ams.org/tran/2012-364-08/S0002-9947-2012-05501-2/  (you may also enjoy chasing the references to Sidorenko's conjecture which is much more general than the Blakley-Roy inequality)

Comment: Thank you, your references are very accurate, as always! I was just playing with graphon generalizations of this statement, and indeed one gets the k-path vs j-path version of Sidirenko's conjecture.

Comment: When S is PSD or k,j are even, then indeed the series $s_k = \langle u, S^k u\rangle$ is completely monotone, by Hausdorff moment problem. This implies for instance the log-convexity and the claim of the conjecture. (My interest/ attempt in the moment problem on [-1,1] that I posted here earlier this week is coming from this application)

Comment: Indeed, Pate's paper seems to be a great resource.

Comment: I'd be quite curious to hear if you discover any extension to Pate's ideas!

Comment: Most definitely!